# Error al ejecutar Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, activity

Al dar clic en un botón, mando a ejecutar un activity donde muestro un layout, pero al intentar ejecutarlo me da el error:

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: md5f22d74140d7efc8f033f3e312f703c5e.NombreActivity
```

Esta es la parte donde mando a llamar el Activity:

```
private void BtnActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NombreActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);

        OnStop();
 }
```

Pero me da error justo en el var intent. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: será porque es Xamarin? https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/

Comment: Si, si es Xamarin, ya había intentado con eso pero marca el mismo error

Comment: Agrega el codigo de tu actividad NombreActivity para ver como defines el nombre de la actividad en el Android Callable Wrapper (ACW) y en que namespace esta definida.

Answer (score 2):

intenta con

```
private void BtnActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NombreActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
 }
```

o

```
private void BtnActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Intent intent= new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, typeof(NombreActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
 }
```

yo no uso esa forma para ejecutar un click .. puedes hacerlo así

```
 Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NombreActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, he intentado las 3 opciones que me das pero me sigue dando el mismo error :( Cada Activity nueva que intento mandar a llamar me marca lo mismo, pero las que ya tenía se ejecutan sin problemas

Comment: en cada activity nueva .. que interesante!! .. por curiosidad no as intentado copiar una ya creada, cambiandole el nombre e intentando acceder a ella? solo por curiosidad para descartar algunos detalles.

Comment: ok .. mira cuando crees un activity revisa si se registra en el archivo manifest , posiblemente lo estés creando mal .. revisa esta documentacion  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :) lo intentaré en cuanto mi Visual Studio se repare (lo puse a reparar por que creí que tal vez sería algo de alguna actualización ya que se me hace muy raro que me haga eso)

Comment: Pues resulta que después de actualizarlo funcionó, ya no me marcaba ese error, peroo ahora ya no me dejaba usar la localización (me marcaba otro error) de tanto que probé pues otra vez me volvió a marcar el error del principio, por lo que volví a reparar pero sigue ese error :( y ahora me dió otro: "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient/IConnectionCallbacksInvoker' from assembly 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Comment: Hola . disculpa e estado de vacaciones ;) ..que bueno que funciono.. el error que muestras al parecer es de la librería google play service. pero ya tendrás que crear un nueva pregunta sobre ello.

Answer (score -2):

Desde `MainActivity.cs`, llama `StartActivity` , pasando el tipo de la Activity a enviar, NombreActivity en tu código:

```
button.Click += delegate {
       StartActivity(typeof(NombreActivity));
};
```

Revisa la documentación:

[Como iniciar un Activity en Xamarin.](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/)

Comment: Ya he intentado y revisado eso pero no resuelve el problema

Comment: No fue mio, pero gracias por tu respuesta